# Compiling on MIPS - ASM

Tags: assembly, mips, ci20

I'm trying to compile Plex Home Theater on my new Ci20 but I'm coming across some build errors which I believe are ASM related, knowing nothing about ASM I was wondering if anyone were able to provide any assistance.

Build Error

```
[ 19%] Building CXX object xbmc/CMakeFiles/xbmc.dir/GUIInfoManager.cpp.o
In file included from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/linux/PlatformInclude.h:25:0,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/system.h:254,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/network/Network.h:26,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/GUIInfoManager.cpp:21:
/home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/linux/XHandlePublic.h:41:1: warning: ‘__stdcall__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
In file included from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/linux/PlatformInclude.h:27:0,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/system.h:254,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/network/Network.h:26,
             from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/GUIInfoManager.cpp:21:
/home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/linux/XTimeUtils.h:28:39: warning: ‘__stdcall__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
In file included from /home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/GUIInfoManager.cpp:55:0:
/home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/utils/MathUtils.h: In function ‘int MathUtils::round_int(double)’:
/home/ci20/plex-home-theater-public/xbmc/utils/MathUtils.h:150:6: error: unknown register name ‘st’ in ‘asm’
make[2]: *** [xbmc/CMakeFiles/xbmc.dir/GUIInfoManager.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [xbmc/CMakeFiles/xbmc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

/xbmc/utils/MathUtils.h

https://github.com/plexinc/plex-home-theater-public/blob/pht-frodo/xbmc/utils/MathUtils.h

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `DISABLE_MATHUTILS_ASM_ROUND_INT` is not set, so, since there is no MIPS version, the compiler is trying to compile the default x86 asm version which obviously won't work.

On closer look, you should probably extend the conditions starting on line 35 to detect your MIPS and disable the asm code. Alternatively as a quick hack you can just stick an unconditional `#define DISABLE_MATHUTILS_ASM_ROUND_INT` along with `#define DISABLE_MATHUTILS_ASM_TRUNCATE_INT` on line 50 to get it to compile.

The logic of the code seems flawed, they should specifically only enable the asm code on architectures they have asm code for, not the other way around...

Comment: Hi, great thank you! Do you have any idea what the defined() needs to be for this architecture? Running "gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null" spits out a lot!

Comment: I'm assuming __mips32__?

Comment: It spits out this.. http://pastebin.com/9RECLStN Not 100% sure on which one I should be using however...

Comment: I vote `__mips__` since that is similar to the others used. I don't even see `mips32` in there...